# Evil pastes after point

Tags: evil

Evil pastes after point; How do I make it paste at point?

`123456|789`

Current behavior:

`1234567sth89`

Desired:

`123456sth789`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `p` is bound to `evil-paste-after`, which pastes after the cursor. But there's also `P` (capitalized), bound to `evil-paste-before`, which pastes before the cursor. So the capitalized `P` should do what you want. You can also rebind the lower `p` key to paste before, if you wish:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "p" 'evil-paste-before)
```